How to properly specify font file for ffmpeg as it's always defaulting to Arial?
When calling ffmpeg it keeps defaulting to Arial-MT / Arial-BoldMT even when specifying a font. How do you correctly specify the fontfile?
When specifying any font it will always default back:
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000001915a83f800] fontselect: (DosisBold, 400, 0) -> ArialMT, 0, ArialMT
I am calling ffmpeg with the following command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles='subtitle.srt':force_style='FontName=DosisBold,Alignment=10,Fontsize=24' output.mp4 -loglevel debug
I have a file called "DosisBold.ttf" in the same folder as ffmpeg. I have already tried FontName=DosisBold.ttf and it also doesn't work. All files are in the same folder as the ffmpeg.exe.
I have converted the .srt file to .ass and specified the font file but it still defaults back to ArialMT.
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize {...}
Style: SubStyle,DosisBold,24 {...}

I am using "ffmpeg-n7.0-latest-win64-gpl-7.0", I have tried different versions of ffmpeg (e.g. "ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl") and still no change. Also tried different fonts / font files and it always defaults back to Arial.

try this :
ffmpeg.exe -i "filename"  -filter_complex "subtitles=filename.ass:fontsdir=./fonts:force_style='FontName=Arial Rounded MT Bold,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF,SecondaryColour=&H000000FF,OutlineColour=&H00000000,BackColour=&H20000000,BorderStyle=4,Fontsize=17'" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 "$filename.mp4"
With a font directory with your font (here : ./font/ARLRDBD.TTF) and the name of your font not ttf file name (here : Arial Rounded MT Bold).
Enjoy
